# How to run a .bat from inside the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

What I want to do is very simple, yet can't find the way to do it.
In my projects I have several .bat files (I know, I'm old) the perform some tasks like running SqlMetal, etc.

I just want to right-click the file and select "run" or something so the bat is executed. **How do I do it?**

*Note: I know I can use Tools -> External Tools, but it's not what I'm looking for*

Comment: Are you looking to do this during the build or just in general?

Comment: So what are you looking for? Tools | External Tools would be the obvious way to do this. What additional functionality are you looking for?

Comment: @Ade: I'm looking at productivity :)

Comment: @Ade: if you have 20+ projects with 3+ bat files: How many menu entries do you end up with?

Comment: OK. Now I understand the problem. You can fix this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

If each project has a few batch files associated with it then why not include them in the project and add a new external tool and link it with a custom menu item to run the tool? This will give you a list of batch files in each project and a context menu command to run them. The only downside is that it isn't file type specific (it will let you run any file as a batch file).

Here's how to do it...

Create an external tool called "Run batch file"

1. Set the Command to: CMD.EXE
2. Set the Arguments to: /c "$(ItemPath)"
3. Set the Initial directory to: $(ItemDir)
4. Check the "use output window" checkbox and then Apply to create the command
5. Note where the new command appeared in the list of commands. The external commands are numbered from 1 starting below the divider bar. #1 is usually "Create GUID"

Now go to Tools -> Customize and select the commands tab.

1. Select the Context menu radio button and select "Project and Solution Context menus | Item" from the dropdown.
2. Now use "Add Command..." to add a new command
3. In the Categories list select "Tools"
4. From the commands select the "External Command #" that corresponds to the position of the "Run Batch file" custom command you noted the number of in step 5 above.
5. Move it to the correct position in the list add keyboard shortcuts etc.
6. Close the dialog.

Now right click on the batch file and you should see a "Run batch file" menu item. This will execute the batch file and show its output in the VS Output window.

Comment: I got some IO exceptions for the program I was running from a batch file. If anyone else runs into these, don't check the "use output window" checkbox to have the batch file run in it's own cmd window.

Comment: Here's how to create an external tool.. see the Adding New Tools section.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx

Comment: Is it possible that this context menu item only appears on `.bat` files? It's quite strange, if I click on it on a .cs file it opens the class, in another instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Used this way too often, would up it each time if I could!

Answer (score 38):

- Right click the batch file in the Solution Explorer
- Select “Open With…”  from the context menu
- Click “Add…”
- In the “Program name” textbox, enter **powershell.exe**
- In the “Friendly name” textbox enter “PowerShell”
- Select “Set As Default”
- Click OK

[via](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2010/01/28/running-batch-files-from-the-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio.aspx)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, "Program name" is now referred to as "Program".

Answer (score 14):

Check out the [Open Command Line](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e84e2cf-2d6b-472a-b1e2-b84932511379) Visual Studio extension.

As per the description, it features:

- Opening of a command line at the root of the project.
- Support for all consoles such as CMD, PowerShell, Bash etc.
- Syntax highlighting, Intellisense and **execution of .cmd and .bat files**.

For files in your solution, a context-menu button shows up.

[image: Execute batch file]

Alternatively, the keyboard shortcut Shift+Alt+5 can be used when editing a batch file. This makes it really easy and fast to execute any batch file - even ones that are not part of your project.

Comment: Handy plugin, and super easy to setup!

Answer (score 6):

Right-click a file in the Solution Explorer window, Open With, click the Add button to add your .bat files.  Use %1 in your .bat to get the path to the selected file.

Comment: Can work if I make another bat or exe that execute the bat. Nice solution also, but the Ade solution is more straightforward to me.

Comment: Batch should contain:   cmd.exe /c %1

Comment: This does not work for me in VS2010. If I type anything other than a valid path, it throws an error.

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't get any of the above to quite work, but this did (VS 2019/2022):

1. Right click a .bat file in *Solution Explorer* and *Open With...*
2. *Add...*
3. Program: **CMD.exe**
4. Arguments: **/c %1**
5. Friendly name: **Command**
6. *OK* and *Set as Default* for double clicking of batch files to run from Solution Explorer as the default (or right click Open With... and select *Command* if you don't want it the default).

[image: Add Progream]

Comment: Finally something that actually works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Merely a suggestion: This is a scenario which can be done with the [VsCommandBuddy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LetsWrappit.VsCommandBuddy) extension. The following configuration is an example:

```
{
    "cmdname": "mk",
    "title": "Run MK.BAT",
    "description": "Run the MK bat file.",
    "cwd": "$(SolutionDir)",
    "filename": "cmd.exe",
    "arguments": "/C mk.bat",
    "async": false
}
```

You can assign shortkeys as well, so you can invoke your batch files with shortcut keys. Output comes in your output pane.