# Using VS 2010 compiler in the VS 2008 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have both installed and also the latest Windows SDK. I'm developing an MFC application but the VS2010 IDE is too slow on my machine (yes, I need to upgrade, but I can't do that right now). Can I use the newer compiler in VS2008? I don't really need most of the features that the IDE provides, just the compiler with the new c++0x features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2008 you have the option of setting the environment paths, i.e. include, lib, binary in the tools options menu.

If you truly must, its possible to point each of these to the equivalent paths from VS 2010.

Note however that in 2010 the option moved from tools->options to a per solution setting.

Once you have done this correctly, you will find that you can use the newer language and library features with the older ide.

an alternative is to spend a little time learning msbuild and use 2008 for browsing and debugging, but build via command line with msbuild from 2010.

Comment: It was not exactly straightforward and I had to recreate the project, but it works great. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the VS 2010 IDE to build a project using the V900 compiler by setting the Platform Toolset property but I don't think you can do this the other way around. Generally Visual Studio tries to support backwards compatability but not forward as this is much harder (predicting the future).

You could also use the VS 2008 IDE and build your project from the command line using MSBuild. You could even link this into the IDE using [custom commands and menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605885/visual-studio-2010-how-to-run-a-bat-from-inside-the-ide/5606276#5606276). This isn't going to give you the same level of intellisense etc for new C++0x language features.

If perf is the issue you could try turning off some of the features in the VS 2010 IDE to speed it up.

Not a great set of choices I know but I think you might be short of options.