# How to execute Post-build event without building the project?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to execute the "Post-build" event without building the project.
is there an option to do so somehow?

[image]

Comment: Just run the same commands from the Developer Command Prompt.

Comment: Looking at your commands and if you are using node.js, I think https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/ Node.js tools for VS will help you to properly setup your development environment.

Answer (score 3):

Launch the Developer Command Prompt:

- Click on the start button.
- Type **Developer Command Prompt** and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Then copy the lines from your Visual Studio:

- Click on the **Edit Post-Build** button.
- Replace the `$(ProjectDir)` with the actual path to your project.
- Copy the lines.
- Paste the lines in the command prompt and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting the commands into a batch file and simply running THAT in your Post Build Events field.

You can add it to your solution and then from Solution Explorer, right click, "Open With", and add a new item called:

- Name: Cmd
- Command: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
- Args: /c "$(ItemPath)"
- Initial Dir: $(ItemDir)

This will allow you to run Batch files from Solution Explorer in the future.  [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605885/how-to-run-a-bat-from-inside-the-ide).

**Bat File Solution 1**

Either pass in the path to run from, or rely on %SolutionPath% (which is an env var that is provided when you run a bat file from Visual Studio).  So this method is doing some directory sniffing.  (note, solution 2 below is probably better - simpler for sure)

```
@echo off
if not [%1]==[] (set "ProjectDir=%1")
if not [%SolutionPath%]==[] (set "ProjectDir=%SolutionPath%\ProjectSubDirectory)
if [%ProjectDir%]==[] (
   echo Error, no Solution Path env var or ProjectDir provided
   exit /b
   goto :eof
)

cd /d %ProjectDir%
ng build
```

Your post build events would then just run `$(ProjectDir)\MyBatchFile.bat "$(ProjectDir)"`

**Bat File Solution 2**

Run in directory relative to location of batch file (a simpler solution).

```
@echo off
pushd "%dp0"
ng build
popd
```

In this case your post build event would simply be: `$(ProjectDir)\MyBatchFile.bat` and it would run in that same directory.  I would recommend this approach for simplicity.

Pushd and popd are similar to "CD" except it's a stack that you can pop out of.  So popd will return you to your original directory.  `%dp0` is the directory of the currently executing bat file.

Comment: %SolutionPath% is path to.sln file, not solution folder.