# Post-Build Event Fails to Run Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event

I recently started adding Post-Build events to my projects and today I came across an annoying issue.

**Post-build event command line:**

```
"$(ProjectDir)PostBuildRelease.bat"
```

**PostBuildRelease.bat** - **1**

```
CMD
SET parameter=%1
CD %1
```

The above errors with message:

> '´╗┐CMD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> "Saved parameter "

Which is strange, because I definitely have another project where the first line reads `CMD` and it works perfectly.

Setting the first line to `SET parameter=%1` also complains that `SET` is not a recognised command.

**PostBuildRelease.bat** - **2**

Trying the same but with an empty file gives this error (build fails):

> The command "C:\Users\name\ITSelfHelp\ITHelp\PostBuildRelease.bat" exited with code 1.

**PostBuildRelease** - **3**

Entering the `CMD` code directly into the Post-Build Event command line field results in a successful post-build event, but this is not ideal for me and seems strange as I can run from an external `.bat` in other projects.

Can anyone explain this behaviour, or let me know how I can debug this?

Comment: Based on the error text you've shown, it looks as if you have some non-printable characters before the `CMD` text.  Look closely at what is shown between the single quotes in the error message: _'´╗┐CMD' is not recognized as an internal or external command_

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://superuser.com/questions/601282/%CC%81-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854360/visual-studio-inserts-invalid-characters-in-batch-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the text editor in `Visual Studio` was encoding my batch script.

#### To recreate this:

- Right-click the solution
- Add file
- Text file
- Rename `file.bat`
- Write the script in `Visual Studio`
- Build
- Check the output window for the error

#### To resolve:

- Delete the file created in `Visual Studio`
- Created a new `.bat` file in the same location using `Windows Explorer`
- Open the file with `Notepad++` and paste in the script
- Save and build

I also noticed that syntax highlighting was not being applying in the file created by `Visual Studio`, which is a bit of a giveaway along with the `´╗┐` in front of the errors.